# Export MongoDB Query to a file

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query which returns a set of single level BSON objects.

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    { $unwind: {
        path: "$addresses", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"}
    },
    { $project: {
        hrId:1, 
        arrayIndex:1,
        location:'$addresses.location', 
        street:'$addresses.street', 
        city:'$addresses.city', 
        state:'$addresses.state', 
        country:'$addresses.country', 
        postCode:'$addresses.postCode'} 
    }])
```

I want to export this to a csv file. I have been looking online for a simple solution but to no avail. I am happy to use a gui/tool to do this if required.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can export result of query to another collection using `$out` operator and then export that collection using `mongoexport`

Comment: @Saleem, this worked. If you create as an answer I will tick it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I have posted my answer below with some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically we can divide problem into two parts.

1) Run aggregation on given collection

2) Export returned results into external file.

MongoDB doesn't directly support exporting of query results however, we can play a trick and make MongoDB do what we want.

**Solution:**

1) Export aggregation results to another collection.

2) Using `mongoexport` export results of that collection into csv file.

Given your example, I'd add `$out` to end of pipeline.

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    { $unwind: {
        path: "$addresses", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"}
    },
    { $project: {
        hrId:1, 
        arrayIndex:1,
        location:'$addresses.location', 
        street:'$addresses.street', 
        city:'$addresses.city', 
        state:'$addresses.state', 
        country:'$addresses.country', 
        postCode:'$addresses.postCode'} 
    },
    { $out: "tempCompaniesCollection"}])
```

This query will store our query result into `tempCompaniesCollection` collection. Now we can run `mongoexport` as

```
mongoexport -d "database" -c "tempCompaniesCollection" -f "hrId,arrayIndex,location,street,city,state,country,postCode" --type csv -o csvfile.csv
```

This will export results to file named `csvfile.csv`.

> Note: `mongoexport` do require filed names to be provided if export type is a csv. See [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#mongoexport) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

MongoChef tool (Free version) allow you to export documents to CSV.
http://3t.io/mongochef/

Comment: seems that the export only works on whole collections, I need to flatten a nested array using the unwind command

Comment: After you run your aggregate query, you can export the resultset as CSV. For that, you can open the "Intelishell" option on top menu and run your script inside that.